# Configuring Iptables for Litespeed port offset with varnish

Tags: iptables

I am trying to get varnish to work with Litespeed on both HTTP and HTTPS.

The problem I am having is that Litespeed offset's BOTH the HTTP and HTTPS port.

So in my current setup, I have set the offset to 8000, this causes Litespeed to listen on both port 8080 and 8443 for HTTP and HTTPS respectively.

I have varnish set up on port 80 and it proxies litespeed on 8080 correctly.

My question is: Is it possible to configure iptables in such a way to allow a user to request Litespeed over HTTPS on port 443, and get a proper response?

I have the following rule for incoming traffic, which as far as I can tell correctly connects to the litespeed socket on 8443:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 443 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 8443
```

What more needs to be done to get this setup to work correctly?

Comment: You're on the right track. The output of `iptables -nvL` and `iptables -nvL -t nat` would help debug this. IIRC you still need to accept traffic to port 8443 in the `INPUT` chain.